# How to trigger a modified event with vue test utils?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I am fairly new to vue, and I have created a `router-link` with a VueRouter to navigate to a certain page.

```
<router-link
  @click.native="onRouteClicked(index)"
/>
```

Now I need to mock this `click.native` function. I know there is a `trigger` function for vue components available from `vue-test-utils`.

But how am I to `click.native` from a trigger ?

my onRouteClicked looks like this

```
methods: {
 onRouteClicked: function (index) {
   this.routedIndex = index;
 }
```

}

my test look like this

```
const myRouteWrapper = navBar.find('[to="/myroute"]');
myRouteWrapper.trigger('click')
expect(myComp.vm.routedIndex).equal(1);
```

the `routedIndex` is not changing at all

Comment: Did you define the `onRouteClicked` function on `methods` object? I believe that should trigger the click event.

Comment: @jom I have updated my question. and yes the onRouteClicked is indeed inside methods object

Comment: TBH, I'm not very familiar with vue-test-utils but I did notice that the [`find`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/find.html#find-selector) method expects [3 different types of selectors](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/selectors.html#selectors). In this case, perhaps I would check if the library actually transforms the individual `router-link`s into HTML anchor tag with `#/myroute` as the `href` attribute, where we could instead do `navBar.find('[href="#/myroute"]')`.

Comment: @jom hi, I found the problem. I was not using the VueRouter with a localVue on my tests. And hence the router-link was never trasformed to <a href="" /> which inturn never actually triggered the click event.

It took a lot of time to find that out though. Should I answer my own question or leave the solution as a comment so that people who are bothered by the problem will find about the solution.

Comment: I would say answer your own question with this solution, people might find this useful in the future, like I did ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so after an entire day of effort I guess I should make this a Q&A.

The problem was that I was not using `VueRouter`. Importing `VueRouter` and my routes and using them with a `localVue` did the trick for me.

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'

var localVueInstance = createLocalVue()
localVueInstance.use(VueRouter)

var router = new VueRouter({
   routes: [],
   mode: 'history'
})
```

And on my tests

```
var wrapper = mount(navBarComp, {
    propsData,
    localVue: localVueInstance,
    router 
});
var myRouteWrapper = wrapper.find('[href="/myroute"]');
myRouteWrapper.trigger('click')
```